# Converting from EPSG:4326-WGS84 to EPSG:4328 - WGS 84 (geocentric) causes shapefile to disappear

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, convert

I need all of my shapefiles to use a projection that measures in meters before I convert them to raster, but wanted to choose a projection that will not cause compatibility issues in the future when imported to other apps.
I chose to convert to EPSG:4328 because it had almost the same name as my current CRS, but when using the Reproject Layer tool, everything disappears.
I don't fully understand how the CRS system works, can someone explain why this happens and what I should be doing to avoid it.

The original shapefile had a CRS of EPSG:6668 - JGD2011 which I then reprojected to EPSG:4326 - WGS84 using the reproject layer tool. Could it have something to do with that?

Comment: May I know the projects CRS used?

Comment: @GforGIS the project CRS is EPSG:6668 - JGD2011

Comment: If you are displaying the 2 sets on the same view, can you try to change the project CRS to EPSG:4326 ?

Comment: How do i change the project CRS haha... I cant find it on google.

Comment: EPSG:4328 is EPSG:4326 rotated, Z becomes east, Y stays the same and X is up/down. Try using a suitable UTM projected coordinate system, probably WGS84/UTM zone 54 North EPSG:32654 which covers the majority of the land area.

Comment: It works! I am going to go read the wikipedia for CRS cause this stuff doesnt make sense to me.

Comment: Can you share what you did?

Comment: I used the Reproject Layer tool to reproject all of my layers to EPSG:32654.